# Ошибка подключения к postgresql через sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Всем привет. Есть вот такой вот модуль подключения к бд

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT
    }
);
```

И в index.js такой вот код

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const sequelize = require('./db');

const app = express();

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();
        app.listen(5000, () => {
            console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
start();
```

При запуске проекта выбрасывает следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, секвалайзу не нравится диалект, хотя вроде как всё написано верно. В общем, не могу решить эту проблему, буду рад помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в неверном пароле. Я указал пароль мастера при входе в pgAdmin. А нужно указать пароль пользователя, которому принадлежит созданная бд

Answer (score 1):

А ещё надо-бы или переключить вывод ошибок в PG на английский "en_US.UTF-8" что делается в конфигах, или переводить ошибку уже у себя в программе с CP1251 -> utf8. Тогда и ошибки будут ясными и понятными.

А ещё плохая практика хранить пароли в environment. Для этого есть специальные программы такие как Vault. Советую почитать документацию на

- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vault

Comment: Ок, спасибо....